# How to run the docker exec commands from a shell script

Tags: docker, shell

While I am able to run the docker exec commands from command line I am unable to  execute the docker exec commands through script file.

Following is what I am trying through shell script..

#!/bin/bash
CONTAINER_NAME=<container_name>

docker exec -it $CONTAINER_NAME  echo -e "max_prepared_transactions = 150" >> /var/lib/postgresq/postgresql.conf

While executing this shell script we always get the o/p as /var/lib/../postgressql.conf file doesn't exists. Where as when we execute this command from a command line we don't encounter any issues. Any quick help to resolve this issue would greatly help us.

Comment: You can't use `docker exec` here.  By the point it's possible to do that, the database process is already running, and if you recreate the container, your local configuration changes will be lost.  Can you use `docker run -v` to inject a configuration file when the container starts instead?

Comment: Thanks. But I already have the conf file existing in the DB container.  I  want o append it with max_prepared_transactions